# How to shoot in Unity in both directions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity and I never coded in C# before neither have I used Unity in the past. All I know is Java and Python. I knew Java since senior year of high school now I am a sophomore in college. I made my project, which consists of my human character, which is supposed to shoot bullets at 12 jaguars. I already implemented all of this from the 2d UFO sample Unity gives us. I have a png picture for my bullet. I really do not know how to implement a bullet. I am required to have the bullet shoot out in two directions. I am starting off gradually by learning how to basic shoot (one direction). I referred to this link and added it to my program and it will not compile after I added the bullet code. I create a sphere into the Unity program as the website said to do and I set the image as the png bullet.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/multiplayer-networking/shooting-single-player

Now here is my code. I downloaded the free latest version of Unity by the way. My game is 2D by the way. It is just cartoons.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//Adding this allows us to access members of the UI namespace including Text.
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CompletePlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;             //Floating point variable to store the player's movement speed.
    public Text countText;          //Store a reference to the UI Text component which will display the number of pickups collected.
    public Text winText;            //Store a reference to the UI Text component which will display the 'You win' message.

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;       //Store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component required to use 2D Physics.
    private int count;              //Integer to store the number of pickups collected so far.

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    public Transform bulletSpawn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Get and store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component so that we can access it.
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

        //Initialize count to zero.
        count = 0;

        //Initialze winText to a blank string since we haven't won yet at beginning.
        winText.text = "";

        //Call our SetCountText function which will update the text with the current value for count.
        SetCountText ();
    }

    //FixedUpdate is called at a fixed interval and is independent of frame rate. Put physics code here.
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Store the current horizontal input in the float moveHorizontal.
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        //Store the current vertical input in the float moveVertical.
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        //Use the two store floats to create a new Vector2 variable movement.
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

        //Call the AddForce function of our Rigidbody2D rb2d supplying movement multiplied by speed to move our player.
        rb2d.AddForce (movement * speed);

        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Fire();
        }


    }

    void Fire()
    {
    // Create the Bullet from the Bullet Prefab
        var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate (
        bulletPrefab,
        bulletSpawn.position,
        bulletSpawn.rotation);

    // Add velocity to the bullet
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 6;

    // Destroy the bullet after 2 seconds
        Destroy(bullet, 2.0f);
    }

     public override void OnStartLocalPlayer ()
    {
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
    }


    //OnTriggerEnter2D is called whenever this object overlaps with a trigger collider.
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        //Check the provided Collider2D parameter other to see if it is tagged "PickUp", if it is...
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("PickUp")) 
        {
            //... then set the other object we just collided with to inactive.
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0);

            //Add one to the current value of our count variable.
            count = count + 1;

            //Update the currently displayed count by calling the SetCountText function.
            SetCountText ();
        }


    }

    //This function updates the text displaying the number of objects we've collected and displays our victory message if we've collected all of them.
    void SetCountText()
    {
        //Set the text property of our our countText object to "Count: " followed by the number stored in our count variable.
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();

        //Check if we've collected all 12 pickups. If we have...
        if (count >= 12)
            //... then set the text property of our winText object to "You win!"
            winText.text = "You win!";
    }
}
```

Other class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CompleteCameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;       //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object


    private Vector3 offset;         //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate () 
    {
        // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: First it sounds like you have a working code for shooting a bullet and you need to also shoot another bullet into some other direction at the same time you shoot the first one. However, in the text you state that " I really do not know how to implement a bullet". So, what is your question here?

Comment: @rs232 My question is how do I get my bullet to work? I already implemented the prefab in Unity and I have to get the bullet coding to get the bullets to shoot. My code is not compiling.

Comment: @potanta if youre making a 2D game dont use 3D object, same goes for rigidbody - you should use rigidbody2d for your bullet aswell. the tutorial you linked is for 3d

Comment: @potanta you have to attach this script to some gameobject in the scene as a component, than your code will get compiled autoamtically, you cant 
 compile it yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Also, if you're getting errors compiling, share those aswell.

Comment: @Fiffe I did what you just said by using a 2d rigidbody and i changed the sphere collider and used a circle collider instead for the bullet. The circle collider is what the player uses to capture the jaguars when the player themselves touch the enemy (jaguars). That should be applied in the bullet since the bullet will also be touching the jaguars

Comment: `bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 6;` I can clearly see this line in your code, you're using Rigidbody 3d here

Comment: @Fiffe  
 
it's compiling saying that network behavior could not be found. It's saying "Are you missing any assemblies?" And do I change the RigidBody element in the < > to RigidBody2d?

Comment: You change it to rigidbody2d in your script and on the game object, also if youre making a single player game you shouldnt be using network behaviours and multiplayer games tutorials. Maybe try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKgtC_Gy65c

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow all the steps in the tutorial link you shared. Looks like you have copied pieces of code and used it in your controller class. OnStartLocalPlayer is marked as overridden, but it is not in Monobehaviour. It is defined in NetworkBehaviour. You have an error due to this. As mentioned in the other comments, the console error tells you where the problem is.

Comment: So should I change it to Network Behavior? I did that and it did not compile still. Also Fiffe's comment said that the link I provided is for 3d only. Now I am stuck. Just now, I added a 2d circle collider as well as a 2d rigid body like Fiffe said.

Comment: it's compiling saying that network behavior could not be found. It's saying "Are you missing any assemblies?"

Comment: Since you know python, you must be aware that to use a module you need to import it first. Same here in C#. You need to import the namespace using UnityEngine.Networking.  Since your requirement is not to develop a multiplayer game, you can remove the OnStartLocalPlayer method and change NetworkBehaviour to MonoBehaviour.